# AttributeError: X962

Tags: python-3.x, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to copy shell command to python:
`ssh -L 8000:localhost:5432 <ssh_host> -l<ssh_user>`

This command work good using with **ssh_config** .

I try this code in python:

```py
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('<ssh_host>', 22),
    ssh_username="<ssh_user>",
    ssh_config_file='<path_to_config>',
    ssh_pkey="<path_to_pkey>",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)
)

server.start()
```

I am get this exception:

```py
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py in _negotiate_keys(self, m)
   2197             self._send_kex_init()
   2198         self._parse_kex_init(m)
-> 2199         self.kex_engine.start_kex()
   2200 
   2201     def _check_banner(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py in start_kex(self)
     40         m.add_string(
     41             self.Q_C.public_bytes(
---> 42                 serialization.Encoding.X962,
     43                 serialization.PublicFormat.UncompressedPoint,
     44             )

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/enum.py in __getattr__(cls, name)
    322             return cls._member_map_[name]
    323         except KeyError:
--> 324             raise AttributeError(name) from None
    325 
    326     def __getitem__(cls, name):

AttributeError: X962
```

I am using this packages:

```
sshtunnel                          0.1.5 
cryptography                       2.7  
paramiko                           2.6.0
```

Comment: FWIW, I got this error with Python 2.7 too...